# Refreshing angular ui-grid on function call

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I initialize a grid inside the controller

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableColumnMenus: false,
  enableGridMenu: true,
  enableSelectAll: true,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
```

Then assign data to it via:

```
$scope.Data = bids.bids;
$scope.gridOptions.data = 'Data';
```

This works. However, I have a get request inside another function in my controller. On the success of this get request, I want to refresh the ui-grid data. I am trying:

```
var SendFilterData = function() {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlString, params: dataToSend})
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.Data = response.data 
        });
};
```

The SendFilterData() gets fired from the view on a button click. I've tried `$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data` as well.

The weird thing is, when the controller is loaded as the user enters, it looks like this SendFilterData is initialized, and the `$scope.Data = response.data` actually works as it's supposed to. But, then it never works on a button click.(I've checked that the function itself does actually fire on button click)

How do I refresh the data in the grid, when this function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In OnRegisterApi() method, add this line as well, (You have to add dependency uiGridConstants)

```
gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
```

And assign data directly to gridOptions.data in SendFilterData() method

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data
```

Comment: Tried it, same thing, runs once on page load. After that, does not change..

Comment: Can you ensure SendFilterData() is called on button click. Maybe through console log, because I am using same code, and it works fine. Even then if it doesn't work, can you please add a plunker